# Deploying a .Net Core app that targets .Net Framework 4.62 to Azure

Tags: .net, azure

We created an application in VS 2017 using a .Net Core Web template.  We since realised that we actually need to reference some packages that are full framework packages.

So we changed the target framework to 4.6.2.

However now when the web app is deployed to azure, I am consistently getting the error:

HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure 
Common causes of this issue: 
The application process failed to start 
The application process started but then stopped 
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port 
Troubleshooting steps: 
Check the system event log for error messages 
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages 
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect 
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

It appears to be failing to even start, but I am unsure of what changes I need to make to get this working.

When I publish it a web.config file is created up on the server, which contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: db77cdb1-05c4-450e-94d8-5dabc48c6d76-->
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add resourceType="Unspecified" modules="AspNetCoreModule" verb="*" path="*" name="aspNetCore"/>
</handlers>
<aspNetCore stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" stdoutLogEnabled="true" processPath=".\Genesis.IdentityServer.exe"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I enabled logging.

The error in the event log up on the azure debug console is as follows:

```
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/>
<EventID>1026</EventID>
<Level>0</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-09-01T06:14:38Z"/>
<EventRecordID>868107718</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>RD0003FFC3731F</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Application: Genesis.IdentityServer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerException at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.ServerSession..ctor() at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener..ctor(Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListenerSettings) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener.MessagePump..ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener.WebListenerOptions>, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite, System.__Canon) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.SingletonCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].VisitCallSite(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceCallSite, System.__Canon) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider+<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(System.Type) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(System.IServiceProvider, System.Type) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.IServiceProvider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build() at Genesis.IdentityServer.Program.Main(System.String[]) </Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
<Event>
<System>
<Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module"/>
<EventID>1000</EventID>
<Level>0</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>Keywords</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-09-01T06:14:38Z"/>
<EventRecordID>868107937</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>RD0003FFC3731F</Computer>
<Security/>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/GENIDENTITYSERVER' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Genesis.IdentityServer.exe ', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : e0434352.</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
</Events>
```

This is baffling me, can I not simply target framework 462 from my .net core app?

EDIT

I turned on detailed errors and now see:

HTTP Error 502.5 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

Most likely causes:
The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.
A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.

Things you can try:
Use DebugDiag to troubleshoot the CGI application.
Determine if a proxy or gateway is responsible for this error.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     AspNetCoreModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    aspNetCore
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://GenIdentityServer:80/favicon.ico
Physical Path      D:\home\site\wwwroot\favicon.ico
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

I put a try catch around the WebHostBuilder().build call and this is what is logged:

```
Access is denied   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.ServerSession..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener..ctor(WebListenerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener.MessagePump..ctor(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Genesis.IdentityServer.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: The stack trace in the event log is almost unreadable and for some reason there is no message associated with the `WebListenerException` that seems to be the culprit. I suggest that you surround the call to `WebHostBuilder.Build()` in your `Main` method with a try-catch and then log any exception thrown in a way so that you can read it (write `exception.ToString()` to the log). One reason you might get a `WebListenerException` is because the process is trying to bind to port that is inaccessible or already in use.

Comment: I updated the issue with the error that I see from the detailed error logs in azure

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didn't realise that this had been added to the code:

//.UseWebListener(options =>
                    //{
                    //    options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
                    //    options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                    //})

which of course won't work on azure!